# Running batch file which runs 2 other batch files from SQL Server job

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd, sql-server-job

I have this step in sql server job
[image]

`AAA.bat` content is this

```
call BBB.bat
call CCC.bat
```

`BBB.bat` and `CCC.bat` each run ETL packages.
When I run above step it throws error

> BBB.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file... CCC.bat is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file

However, when I replace `AAA.bat` with either `BBB.bat` or `CCC.bat` it works as intended.

Comment: Call the `bat` files with their full (UNC) path. But why a batch file? Wouldn't you be better off with Powershell? Batch is pretty dated now.

Comment: @Larnu - While I would agree that getting onto PowerShell is a good idea, it would not change anything about this problem. The issue is the PATH to the executable, regardless of whether it is .bat, .ps1, .py, .pl, .exe, or anything else.

Comment: @lit I mention the paths of the at the start of my comment. *"Call the `bat` files with their full (UNC) path"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `BBB.bat` and `CCC.bat` in the same directory as `AAA.bat`? You need to set the working directory first. In `AAA.bat` add the following at the top of the file:

```
cd /d D:\Path\Client1
```

Or, call `BBB.bat` and `CCC.bat` using their full path.

A possibly better solution, depending on your environment and needs, would be to have your job contain two steps, each one calling the appropriate batch file (`BBB` or `CCC`) separately. That way, if you have a failure, its very obvious which batch file had a problem.

Comment: AAA, BBB and CCC have same path. Is it possible to do it without setting path? Since i'm going to have many other jobs for Client2, Client3, etc.

Comment: I though maybe there is command which will set directory to the directory where current file (aaa) is